# Running a task within a custom task in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to write a custom Gradle plugin using Java. One of the things I'll need to do within this plugin is copy all the defined dependencies into a folder. I've found out how you can do this using a task in the build.gradle file:

```
task copyDeps(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtime
    into 'build/lib'
}
```

However, I'm struggling to figure out how I would run this task from within my own custom task. I've tried doing this:

```
public class MyTask extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    public void executeTask() {
        Copy copyTask = new Copy();
        copyTask.into(libFolder).from(getProject().getConfigurations().getByName("runtime").execute();
    }
}
```

However, when I run this I get the exception:

```
Task of type 'org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy' has been instantiated directly which is not supported. Tasks can only be created using the DSL.
```

I understand what it is trying to say, but I haven't been able to find out I would be able to execute this task using the DSL from within Java.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't create tasks within tasks in Gradle. If you want to write a custom plugin with a task as you have described, the way to go is to write a custom plugin class and within that plugin class you declare a task of type `Copy` that does what you want to do. This could look like this:

```
class MyCustomPlugin extends Plugin<Project> {

    void apply(Project project) {
        project.tasks.create("copyDeps", Copy.class) {
            from configurations.runtime
            into 'build/lib'
        }
    }

}
```

Now, if you apply this plugin within your buildscript:

```
apply plugin:MyCustomPlugin
```

you automatically have a task named "copyDeps" of type `Copy` in your build.

### One more thing:

Sometimes it can be convenient to do a simple copy operation in a custom task. This can be done using the `project.copy` util method. A task like this would look this

```
public class MyTask extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    public void executeTask() {
        project.copy {
            into(libFolder)
            from(project.configurations.runtime)
        }
    }
}
```

With plain java it would look like this:

```
public class MyTask extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    public void executeTask() {
        project.copy(new Action<CopySpec>() {
            @Override
            void execute(CopySpec copySpec) {
                copySpec.into(libFolder);
                copySpec.from(getProject().getConfigurations().getByName("runtime"));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

### One last thing:

You should never call `Task#execute()` your own. This method is considered to be internal API in Gradle and executing it directly causes unexpected behaviour. (for example it breaks Gradles' incremental build feature)

Comment: Great, thanks for the information. I want the copying to happen as part of my task, so I think it makes sense to use the project.copy method. Do you have any idea how I would write this in Java? I can't figure it out. Might be time to pick up some Groovy as it hasn't been easy figuring out how to write these plugins in Java.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a plain java snippet for doing a copy within your task